# If $[F : F_p] = n$, does $F$ have $p^n$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> If $[F : F_p] = n$, does $F$ have $p^n$ elements?

My book seems to be implying that this is true but I'm not sure why.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is true.  In fact, if $K$ is a field with $q$ elements, and $[F:K] = n$, then $F$ is a field with $q^n$ elements.  To see _why_ this true, what does $[F:F_p] = n$, mean exactly?

Comment: $F$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F_p$...so there are $n$ vectors in $F$ that are not in $p$.  So everything in $F$ can be written as $f_1v_1 + f_2v_2 + ... f_nv_n$. ...Okay, now I feel stupid.

Comment: There is NO reason to feel stupid (or to think you are "bad" at math)!  Talking things out is helpful... (:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Comment converted to answer:*

Yes it is true:

If $K$ is a finite field with $q$ elements, and $F$ is an extension field of degree $[F:K] = n$, then $F$ is a finite field with $q^n$ elements.

To see this, note that $[F:K] = n$ means that $F$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$, and hence, $F$ exhibits an $n$-dimensional basis over $K$.  Calling that basis $x_1, \dots , x_n$, then everything in $F$ can be written uniquely as $a_1 x_1 + \dots + a_n x_n$ (where $a_i \in K$).  Since there are $q$ choices for each $a_i$, it follows $F$ must have $q^n$ elements.